# Mongoose update only fields available in request body

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to update one document using `findOneAndUpdate` and `$set` but I clearly missing something very crucial here because the new request is overwriting old values.

My `Device` schema looks like this:

```
{
  deviceId: {
    type: String,
    immutable: true,
    required: true,
  },
  version: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  deviceStatus: {
    sensors: [
      {
        sensorId: {
          type: String,
          enum: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
        },
        status: { type: Number, min: -1, max: 2 },
      },
    ],
  },
}
```

And I am trying to update the document using this piece of code:

```
const deviceId = req.params.deviceId;

Device.findOneAndUpdate(
    { deviceId },
    { $set: req.body },
    {},
    (err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send({ success: true });
        }
    }
);
```

And when I try to send a request from the postman with the body that contains one or multiple sensors, only the last request is saved in the database.

```
{
    "deviceStatus": {
    "sensors": [
        {
            "sensorId": "test",
            "status": 1
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to update values that are already in the database based on `req.body` or add new ones if needed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html#up._S_set) said:

> The $set operator replaces the value of a field with the specified
> value.

You need the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/index.html) operator, it appends a specified value to an array.

Having this documents:

```
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    "array": [
      2,
      4,
      6
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    "array": [
      1,
      3,
      5
    ]
  }
]
```

**Using $set operator:**

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
{
  $set: {
    array: 10
  }
})
```

Result:

```
 {
   "_id": 1,
   "array": 10
 }
```

**Using $push operator:**

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 1
},
{
  $push: {
    array: 10
  }
})
```

Result:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "array": [
      2,
      4,
      6,
      10
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push new sensors every time you make request then update your code as shown below:

```js
const deviceId = req.params.deviceId;

Device.findOneAndUpdate(
    { deviceId },
    { 
      $push: {
        "deviceStatus.sensors": { $each: req.body.sensors }
      } 
    },
    {},
    (err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send({ success: true });
        }
    }
);
```

Update to the old answer:

If you want to update sensors every time you make request then update your code as shown below:

```js
const deviceId = req.params.deviceId;

Device.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "deviceId": deviceId },
    { "deviceStatus": req.body.sensors },
    { upsert: true },
    (err, docs) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send({ success: true });
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for help but in my case I need to update existing one or add new one using same request body. Can I join $set and $push togother or maybe there is another way to achieve that?

Comment: Then directly assign the value to the "deviceStatus" field. Check the edited answer.

Comment: Also set option upsert to true, if you want to add document for non matching conditions.

Answer (score 0):

you want to using `$push` and `$set` in one findOneAndUpdate, that's impossible, I prefer use `findById()` and `process` and `save()` ,so just try

```
let result = await Device.findById(deviceId )
//implementation business logic on result

await result.save()
```